# How do I build an S3 uploader and retrieve S3 data in Angular2 with the aws-sdk

Tags: angular, aws-sdk

It seems that everyone can explain how to send a file to S3, but unfortunately I haven't found anything about how to store the data from S3 back into my Angular2 MEAN stack application. I'm guessing this means i'm missing something simple.

Currently, I can upload to S3, but I get back the js object a couple seconds later and even though I've tried subscribing to the bucket.upload, nothing I do seems to work to capture the s3 bucket info.

Can someone help me see what I may be missing here?

Here is what I am doing.

My template:

```
<div class="form-group"  >
<input type="file" (change)="uploadToS3($event)" #input />
</div>
```

My Component:

```
export class ProfileImgUploadComponent implements OnInit {
// This class and template is to upload img to S3 and assign to profile
@Input() profile: Profile;
pic_main_loc = '';
file: File;
items: any[] = [];

policy: String;
s3signature: String;


constructor(private router: Router, private awsService: AWSUploadService, private http: Http ) {}

ngOnInit() {
    //console.log(this.profile.first_name)
}

uploadToS3(file: any){

    require('aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk');

    var AWS = window.AWS;
    var file = file.target.files[0];

    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials("myID", "MyPassword");

    var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'pcvidistorage1'}});
    var params = {Key: file.name, ContentType: file.type, Body: file, "x-amz-acl": "public-read"};


    console.log(params);

    bucket.upload(params, function (err, data)
    {
        console.log(file.name);
        console.log(err, data);
        console.log('i am here');
        return data
    });

}

//Map file on change
onChange(event) {
    var files = event.srcElement.files;
    this.file = files[0];
    console.log(this.file);
}
```

Comment: You are exposing your credentials with :
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.Credentials("AKIAJ2N2UW2T5YIL662Q", "szwvBjPtJ0zvZeaBrIU7Yl/wuG7BKGHCQe+eCiyw");

this is so bad in term of security

Comment: Thanks for the note. These were old inactive credentials luckily, don't know how I missed that ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching and hacking on this a while, here is what I figured out.

I created a aconfig.json file with the amazon credentials which looks like this:

```
{ "accessKeyId": "*****YourAccessKey****", "secretAccessKey": "***YourSecretKey****" }
```

I moved the upload of the file into the Node side of things as I determined it made more sense to upload locally, create an upload object, verify the file conforms to standards and then upload to s3. The contents of the Node (ExpressJS) route file look like the file pasted below.

```
router.post('/sendToS3', function(req, res) {

var fs = require('fs');
var multer = require('multer');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var path = require('path');

var awsCredFile = path.join(__dirname, '.', 'aconfig.json');

console.log('awsCredFile is');
console.log(awsCredFile);

AWS.config.loadFromPath(awsCredFile);

var s3 = new AWS.S3();

var photoBucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myGreatBucket'}});

var sampleFile = {
    "_id" : 345345,
    "fieldname" : "uploads[]",
    "originalname" : "IMG_1030.JPG",
    "encoding" : "7bit",
    "mimetype" : "image/jpeg",
    "destination" : "./public/images/uploads",
    "filename" : "31a66c51883595e74ab7ae5e66fb2ab8",
    "path" : "/images/uploads/31a66c51883595e74ab7ae5e66fb2ab8",
    "size" : 251556,
    "user" : "579fbe61adac4a8a73b6f508"
};

var filePathToSend = path.join(__dirname, '../public', sampleFile.path);


function uploadToS3(filepath, destFileName, callback) {
    photoBucket
        .upload({
            ACL: 'public-read',
            Body: fs.createReadStream(filepath),
            Key: destFileName.toString(),
            ContentType: 'application/octet-stream' // force download if it's accessed as a top location
        })
        // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#httpUploadProgress-event
        .on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt) { console.log(evt); })
        // http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html#send-property
        .send(callback);
}

multer({limits: {fileSize:10*1024*1024}});

console.log('filePathToSend is ');
console.log(filePathToSend);

uploadToS3(filePathToSend, sampleFile.filename, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(500).send('failed to upload to s3').end();
    }
    res.status(200)
        .send('File uploaded to S3: '
            + data.Location.replace(/</g, '&lt;')
            + '<br/><img src="' + data.Location.replace(/"/g, '&quot;') + '"/>')
        .end();
});

console.log('uploading now...');

});
```

My ProfileInputComponent now has this upload method on it

```
    upload() {
    console.log('this.createdProfile before upload');
    console.log(this.createdProfile);
    this.uploadFileService.makeFileRequest("http://localhost:3000/upload", this.createdProfile.profileId, this.filesToUpload)
        .then(
            (result) => {
                this.imageUploaded = true;
                this.uploadFile = result.obj.path;
    },
            (error) => {
                console.log('We are in error');
                console.error(error);
    });
}
```

The makeFileRequest method inside of the upload-file.service looks like this:

```
    makeFileRequest(url: string, profileId, files: Array<File>) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token') ? '?token=' + localStorage.getItem('token') : '';
    console.log('profileId in upload service is: ');
    console.log(profileId);
    const profileParam = 'profileId=' + profileId;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var formData: any = new FormData();
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            formData.append("uploads[]", files[i], files[i].name);
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                if (xhr.status == 200) {
                    console.log('xhr.status is 200');
                    resolve(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                } else {
                    console.log('xhr.status is NOT 200');
                    reject(xhr.response);
                }
            }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", url+token+'&'+profileParam, true);
        xhr.send(formData);
    });

}
```

So at this point, the file is uploaded to a local location. Now is when I will create one more service call to the node method I mentioned above. I know this will work though, because the node method was tested with an actual JSON object created by this service.

This took me a while to finally get working, but if you setup the route below, update the sampleFile JSON to point to a real file on your system and hit it with Postman it will publish a file to your S3 account.

Hope this helps. Happy to answer any questions on this as I think I finally had my s3 A Ha moment.